# SQL writing a query for median value of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, median

I need to find out median value of a column named 'lat_n' from table 'Station'
I have created a table view having a new column named num_row and old column 'lat_n' from station named as median_table
I have stored value of total rows in the table view in a variable named @num_rows.
now I'm using this to find median value but it shows syntax errors, please help.

```
create view median_table as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS num_row, lat_n FROM station order by lat_n);
select @num_rows:= count(num_row) from median_table
select avg(lat_n) as median_val from median_table
    where num_row in ((@num_rows+1)//2+(@num_rows+2)//2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions.  Here is one method:

```
select avg(lat_n)
from (select row_number() over (order by lat_n) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (order by lat_n desc) as seqnum_desc,
             t.*
      from median_table t
     ) t
where seqnum_asc - seqnum_desc in (-1, 0, 1)
```